# See beyond grayscale/saturation using CSS or Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-web-designer

Summary of what I'm trying to achieve: I want to make my entire website in grayscale or saturation 0 and a div which follows the cursor to display the colors under that "mask" or div which acts like a mask.

I tried different approaches for this but I can't get it. I tried using CSS, with filter property or backdrop-filter. I tried finding the solution with Google Web Designer

In GWD the mask works just in one way, not like in photoshop.For example, in photoshop you can pun a top layer to remove the saturation than put a mask on it and reverse the mask to for it to apply outside the area created.

[mask in pohotoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csdyW.jpg)

But in GoogleWebDesigner the mask is only applied on the area created, you can reverse it [mask in googlewebdesigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoGC4.png)

Do you have other suggestions how to approach this ? another method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a combination of `clip-path` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)) and `backdrop-filter` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)). These are both quite new, so check whether they are suitable for you browser support requirements.

Most of the explanation is in the code comments, but a basic summary:

- Fix an element over the entire document, and use `backdrop-filter` to make everything greyscale.
- Use clip-path to only apply that filter to a rectangle in the center.
- Use JS to offset the element so that the center remains over the cursor.

```js
// This simply listens for mouse movenet and sets the CSS variables to the current X/Y
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor")
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.style.setProperty("--x", `${e.pageX}px`);
  cursor.style.setProperty("--y", `${e.pageY}px`);
});
```

```css
/* This body style is just an example to make the demo work, it is not relevant to the solution*/
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff002f 10%, #2bcc33 10%, #2bcc33 20%, #0c12cc 20%, #0c12cc 30%, #0ddec6 30%, #0ddec6 40%, #d0db00 40%, #d0db00 50%, #ff002f 50%, #ff002f 60%, #2bcc33 60%, #2bcc33 70%, #0c12cc 70%, #0c12cc 80%, #0ddec6 80%, #0ddec6 90%, #d0db00 90%, #d0db00 100%);
  background-size: 141.42px 141.42px;
}

/* This container covers the page and prevent the mask from blocking clicks or making the page scrollable*/
.cursorContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor {
  /* These are set by JS and used to keep the box over the cursor */
  --x: 0px;
  --y: 0px;
  /* These are each half of the box's width and height respectively */
  --boxX: 60px;
  --boxY: 40px;
  /* These work out the boundries of the clip path from the sizes above */
  --boxUpperX: calc(50% + var(--boxX));
  --boxLowerX: calc(50% - var(--boxX));
  --boxUpperY: calc(50% + var(--boxY));
  --boxLowerY: calc(50% - var(--boxY));
  
  position: fixed;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200vw;
  /* Use the variables above to keep this over the cursor */ 
  left: calc(-100% + var(--x));
  top: calc(-100% + var(--y));
  /* Apply the greyscale filter to the webpage behind this element */ 
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Only apply that filter to this area (Basically a thick rectangle with a gap for the colour to appear through) */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, var(--boxLowerX) 100%, var(--boxLowerX) var(--boxLowerY), var(--boxUpperX) var(--boxLowerY), var(--boxUpperX) var(--boxUpperY), var(--boxLowerX) var(--boxUpperY), var(--boxLowerX) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursorContainer">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Sadly, it doesn't even work on the latest Safari yet so its very limited atm. Cool solution though.

Comment: Very impressive , thank you so much for your help. I really do appreciate it!
Is there a way to make it circle instead of rectangle? I tried using a clip-path generator but I don't know how to do it.